# Is it feasible to have a coffee shop accepting ethereum?

Tags: transactions

I know that there are transaction fees involved in ether transactions. What if want to have a coffee shop which sells coffee of 1$(dollar) value in ether. Is such a thing feasible considering the transaction fees involved? What would be the transaction fees in such case? Would miners consider mining such small transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the transaction fees in such case?

Your safe Tx Fee can be as low as `7.3 cents` right now according to [ETH Gas Station](https://ethgasstation.info/).

> Would miners consider mining such small transactions?

Yes. Even if tx fee will be 1 gwei (4 gwei is safe) they will probably mine your tx but it will take usually much more time.

> Is such a thing feasible considering the transaction fees involved?

As you can see from the example, 7 cents is not so much. Considering margin of coffee your business idea is pretty realistic.